# Inform AucTeX about index style file

Tags: latex, auctex

I am currently working on a document for which I use a custom index style file. When I type `C-c C-c` to compile my document, Emacs/AucTeX offers to run its `Index` command (which I assume runs `makeindex`). This works fine, except that the style is not applied. Is there a way to tell AucTeX that it should use a certain style file for this specific LaTeX file (i.e. that it should run `makeindex -s mystile.ist`)? I looked around in AucTeX's customizations, but couldn't find any commands related to indexing.

**Edit**
It seems that the index command is defined in `TeX-command-list`. Is there a way to overwrite this for a given file? For example, by adding something to the `Local Variables` at the bottom of my `.tex` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very good question, it's strange that no one ever asked for this feature.  Luckily, AUCTeX allows you to expand it with a bit of Lisp code.  The trick is to add a new command to `TeX-command-list` and a new expander to `TeX-expand-list` (for more details see [`(info "(auctex)Selecting a command")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Selecting-a-Command)).

Add the following to your init file:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(progn
     ;; Define a new safe buffer-local variable to change its value on a
     ;; per-file basis
     (defvar mg-TeX-index-options "")
     (make-variable-buffer-local 'mg-TeX-index-options)
     (put 'mg-TeX-index-options 'safe-local-variable 'stringp)
     ;; Add new expansion string
     (add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list
          '("%(indexopts)" (lambda () mg-TeX-index-options)))
     ;; Add new command.
     (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
          '("MyIndex"
            "makeindex %(indexopts) %s"
            TeX-run-index nil t
            :help "Run makeindex to create index file"))))
```

Compile the index with `MyIndex` command rather than `Index` when you need to specify a style file, and add `mg-TeX-index-options` as a file local variable, that is a string holding the options you want to pass to `makeindex`:

```latex
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% mg-TeX-index-options: "-s mystile.ist"
%%% End:
```

Comment: This variable can't be safe without a lot more validation. It allows executing arbitrary code via the command shell.

Comment: I can remove the `safe-local-variable` in order to make users more conscious about what they're going to do, but that's the only way to make it work.

Comment: I am not able to make it work with this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65247/index-with-an-initial-letter-of-the-group is it my fault?

Comment: @giordano Thanks for this advice.  It works for me partially.  The cons of this solution are (to me): it only works locally, i.e. if you are compiling from this buffer.  If you split your document with `\include`, this won't work, as `MyIndex` will be run without style file.   Furthermore, `C-c C-a` won't use `MyIndex` but still plain `Index` (and of course again no index style!).  Your answer is now 3,5 yrs old, still AUCTeX uses the old mechanism as before.  Furthermore, xindy isn't even mentioned by AUCTeX at all, which I think, it should.  This part needs an update, as BibLaTeX has got.